# How can I recompose a Q function call as a string from a list of arguments?

Tags: c#, kdb

I am using C# to execute q code against a KDB database using the `c.cs` library provided by KX. I provide arguments in the form of objects (integers, strings, Dict instances etc.) to the `c.k` method in that library, and this all works fine. However, when I have a query that doesn't work using this method, invariably what I want to do is take the query I've just executed through the C# adapter and re-execute it in a Q console so that I can tinker with it and work out what I did wrong. The problem is, in the C# environment what I have as arguments to my Q function (in some cases somewhat complicated dictionary-based trees of arguments), It's a real pain to manually convert my arguments into the `func[arg1;arg2;arg3...];` format expected by the Q console. What I'd really like to be able to do is pass my arguments to a function that would recompose the original query in a syntax that would enable me to easily re-execute the original query in the console. Something like this:

**In C#**

```
var client = new c();
[connect]
var funcName = "myFunc";
var arg1 = "test";
var arg2 = 12345;
var arg3 = new c.Dict(new [] { "a", "b" }, new [] { true, false });
try {
  var result = c.k(funcName, arg1, arg2, arg3);
} catch {
  var composedStatement = c.k("getComposedStatement", funcName, new[] { arg1, arg2, arg3 });
  // composedStatement: "myFunc[`test;12345i;`a`b!10b];"
  Logger.LogError("KDB Query failed: " + composedStatement);
}
```

**In Q**

```
getComposedStatement:{[funcName;arguments]
  :(string funcName),"[",(qWizardryGoesHere arguments),"];";
  }
```

Hopefully that's clear what I'm trying to achieve. The important thing is that the `getComposedStatement` function takes a function name, and an *arbitrary* number of arguments that could be of any type, including nested types (lists of lists, list of dictionary, dictionary of different types etc.) and returns a statement that can be directly copied and pasted into a Q console for execution.

Comment: Try following : var result = c.k(funcName, new object[] {arg1, arg2, arg3});

Comment: Apologies, I think you may have missed the point of my question. var result = c.k(funcName, arg1, arg2, arg3); works fine (I also do it the way you suggested sometimes). What I'm looking for is a general purpose way of recomposing an executable Q statement from object arguments, so that if myFunc has a bug I can test it with arguments to find out why. It's the Q part that I'm looking for help with - specifically where I've said "qWizardryGoesHere" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking in a kdb function.

Using `.Q.s1` to get the string representation for each parameter and then `sv` to get `;` separated string for the parameters. There is also some extra bits to create a `.` / `@` apply:

```
getComposedStatement:{
    // conditional to create a . or @ apply depending on number of parameters
    // @ apply will only work with 1 parameter 
    $[1 < count y;".";"@"],
       "[`",x,";(",(";" sv .Q.s1 each y),")]"
}
```

Useful links:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qs1-string-representation

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/sv/

Edit: A better approach to help you debug in q would be to avoid the string based solution entirely and create a debug variable. You could then have the function and params already available in the q console which can be ran with `eval .debug`

```
createDebug:{
    // simply create a list with function name and parameters
    // assign it to the .debug namespace so it is available 
    // outside of the function call.
    .debug:(,/)enlist each x,y;

    }

testFunc:{1 2 3!(x;y;z)}

createDebug[`testFunc;("test";12345i;`a`b!10b)]
show .debug
(`testFunc;"test";12345;(`a`b)!10b)

eval .debug
key value
1   "test"
2   12345
3   (`a`b)!10b
```

Edit 2:

Since OP is having issues with objects greater than 2000 characters, another way to do this would be to make use of JSON. I'm not to sure how this will be handled in C# but it's worth a try.

```
getComposedStatement:{
    
    (x;.j.j each y)    

    }
    

// 3rd arg is a very large dictionary
getComposedStatement[`testFunc;("test";12345i;(til 2000)!2000?`3)]

(`testFunc;(""test"";"12345";{"0":"gia","1":"dmj","2":"pnh","3":"ofc","4":"hon","5":"jjb", ...
```

You will then have to use a run function on the other side to convert the json back:

```
runComposedStatement:{
    
    eval (first x),.j.k each last x    

}

runComposedStatement[getComposedStatement[`testFunc;("test";12345i;(til 2000)!2000?`3)]]

(1j, 2j, 3j)!("test";12345f;(`0`1`2`3`4`5`6`7`8`9`10`11`12`13`14`15 ...
```

I don't want to post the entire dictionary but I verified it was complete. Hopefully that can achieve what you want or at least one step closer. May need more to handle the JSON.

Comment: Excellent - that's exactly what I needed, thanks very much!  Just one issue with it really - .Q.s1 seems to be hardcoded to constrain it's output to 1999 characters - you might think that would be enough for me, but you'd be wrong. Any idea how to increase that limit?

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure that limitation is .Q.s1 but I will have to look into it. However, I think a different approach will get the desired debuging you need. See edit above

Comment: Thanks Matt. I had actually considered that approach, and will do it that way if necessary - I prefer the .Q.s1 approach though because the context in which I'm using this is a number of production apps, lots of different queries, different servers and trying to capture failing queries in logs for later review. Storing the params in memory on the server is great for debugging, but I keep hitting production problems caused by unexpected inputs from user-generated data, and in-memory storage of arguments will be lost of Q processes are restarted.

Comment: With regards to the .Q.s1 issue, you can reproduce it with the statement "count .Q.s1 `long_string_with_2000_or_more_chars" - the result will always be 1999 and the presented string will end with ".." - this is quite an annoying limitation to what is otherwise a perfect solution to my problem.

Comment: I think the significance of the 2000 character limit is it's the maximum size you can expand the console to. After every restart I habitually run \c 10000 10000 to max out the console size but when I then run \c it reports the console size as 2000 2000i , which is obviously the limit. .Q.s1 must obviously be making use of the configured console size to constrain the output

Comment: I've accepted this answer - it's not 100% what I was after because of the 2000 character limit, but it's close enough. If you have any further thoughts on ways around the 2000 character limit I'd be very grateful.

Comment: yeah sorry I've been too busy to come up with anything just yet, the 2000 character limit is to do with the max character limit of the console. I'm not convinced you can copy a 2000 character bit of code into the console but haven't verified yet. I'll take another look this evening and revert back.

Comment: Hi Matt. I’m using the KX Control web UI and in there you can definitely copy/paste more than 2000 characters and execute.

Comment: Yeah I was referring to the console, IDEs will be fine and you will need to use one for this. I have a final option to hopefully achieve what you want using JSON. See Edit above

Comment: Ah nice one Matt, yeah that looks like it'll do what I want - I'll try it on Monday morning, but I'm sure it'll work - thanks again for the effort you've put in to help with this, I really appreciate it :)